# Hibernate query.executeUpdate() executing many queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I'm creating a query with HQL to update several objects at once, so hibernate doesn't need to synchronize each object individually. Here is my query:

```
String queryString = "UPDATE transaction SET value = :newValue, date = :date, user = :user WHERE id in (:idList)";

final Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);

query.setParameter("date", entityList.get(0).getRegDate());
query.setParameter("user", entityList.get(0).getRegUser());
query.setParameter("newValue", newValue);

query.executeUpdate();
```

So I would make one query to update a list of entities. But when I execute this, the console outputs this

```
Hibernate: 
update
    TRANSACTION_RECEIPT 
set
    DATE=?,
    USER=?,
    ACQ_ID=?,
    ESTIMATED_DATE=?,
    STATUS=?,
    VALUE=? 
where
    ID=?
Hibernate: 
update
    TRANSACTION_RECEIPT 
set
    DATE=?,
    USER=?,
    ACQ_ID=?,
    ESTIMATED_DATE=?,
    STATUS=?,
    VALUE=? 
where
    ID=?
Hibernate: 
update
    TRANSACTION_RECEIPT 
set
    DATE=?,
    USER=?,
    ACQ_ID=?,
    ESTIMATED_DATE=?,
    STATUS=?,
    VALUE=? 
where
    ID=?
Hibernate: 
update
    TRANSACTION_RECEIPT 
set
    STATUS=?,
    regdate=?,
    reguser=? 
where
    ID in (
        ? , ? , ?
    )
```

It updates other values that I don't want to persist either. I tried using the session#evict to detach the entities from context, right before the executeUpdate():

```
 for (BaseEntity entity : entityList) {
    session.evict(entity);
 }
```

But it didn't change anything.
How can I prevent the additional update lines?
I'm using sessionFactory from Hibernate and I don't have entityManager on the project.

Comment: So you are basically trying to work around hibernate instead of using it. Why not simply enable batch statements and ordering of updates. That is probably easier and even faster then your own solution (and you don't really want to maintain all those update queries yourself). If you are worried about the fields you can use `@DynamicUpdate` to only persist the fields that have changed. But detecting those changes comes with a cost of course.

Comment: But would it be faster than a single update query? I don't know how batch update works exactly, but I tried something similar to entityManager#criteriaUpdate

Comment: That will issue a single update with multiple values (providing the jdbc driver supports batch statements). So it is a single query and it is easier to do because you can now leave it to hibernate. Also have you measured the real gain you have in comparison with plain hibernate. Is that worth writing all the statements yourself and writing code that someone else probably doesn't expect...